# detectar duplicados consecutivos en una lista

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Quiero detectar todos los números duplicados consecutivos en una lista. Esto lo estoy intentando con:

```
sublist( [], _ ):-!.
sublist( [X|XS], [X|XSS] ) :- sublist( XS, XSS ),!.
sublist( [X|XS], [_|XSS] ) :- sublist( [X,XS], XSS ).

consecutive_duplicates(Y,LS):-
    member(Y,LS)
    , sublist([Y,Y],LS)
    .
```

Salida:

```
consecutive_duplicates(X,[1,1,4,3,2,2,4]).
```

> X = 1 ;

> X = 1 ;

> X = 2 ;

> X = 2 ;

> false.

Sin embargo yo esperaba la siguiente salida:

> X = 1;

> X = 2;

¿Qué necesito cambiarle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `append/3`:

```
consecutive_duplicates(X,L):-
 append(_, [X, X|_], L).
```

Sin embargo esta solución aún puede incluir repetidos si aparece más de una vez el mismo número duplicado:

```
?- consecutive_duplicates(X,[1,1,4,3,2,2,4]).
X = 1 ;
X = 2 ;
false.

?- consecutive_duplicates(X,[1,1,1,4,4,1,1]).
X = 1 ;
X = 1 ;
X = 4 ;
X = 1 ;
false.
```

Para evitarlo puedes usar `setof/3`:

```
consecutive_duplicates(X,L):-
 setof(X, H^T^append(H, [X, X|T], L), L1),
 member(X, L1).
```

Y ahora las pruebas obtienen la siguiente salida:

```
?- consecutive_duplicates(X,[1,1,4,3,2,2,4]).
X = 1 ;
X = 2.

?- consecutive_duplicates(X,[1,1,1,4,4,1,1]).
X = 1 ;
X = 4.
```